# Javascript: I need to find the average, min max sum and product of three variable

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project on finding the Min, Max, sum, product, and average of three numbers inputted by the user on the website and I just can't figure out how to get it to work and I have been working on it for the last two days and just can't seem to understand how to get it to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Homework Number Two Part Two</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content= "My Homework Website">
    </head>
    <script>
        function process()
        {
        var x, y, result;
        x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        z = document.getElementById("num3").value;
        result = (x+y+z)/3;
        document.getElementById("result").value = ("The result is " + result);
        }
        </script>
        
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
        <form name="myform">
        First Number: <input type="text" id="num1" size="10"><br><br>
        Second Number: <input type="text" id="num2" size="10"><br><br>
        Third Number: <input type="text" id="num3" size="10"><br><br>
        Results: <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="result"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="process()" value="SUBMIT">
        <input type="reset" value="RESET">
```

Comment: hint 1: inputs's values are always strings.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I wanted to fix your snippet but your entire HTML structure is broken. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#anatomy_of_an_html_document

Comment: That is quite important hint, as almost everything later is quite aftected by that

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/nkbf09du/

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` on each variable because every value is regarded as a string. So instead of doing the arithmetic operations, your code is actually concatenating strings.
Your code should look something like this to have an expected output.

```
x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
y = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
z = parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
result = (x+y+z)/3
document.getElementById("result").value = ("The result is " + result);
```

Here is the correct program 
https://jsfiddle.net/seh4wbmt/1/

For more detail follow this documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the `<script>...</script>` tags to the end of the file before `</body>` to make sure that the DOM is fully loaded. Also because you are using a form, each time you click the button submit the page will reload, to prevent that behavior you have to add `event.preventDefault()` onSubmit event.